# Mapping of Multi-valued column from one table to another table using join in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am creating a report using SQL in DB2 and I have a field in one of the tables which stores multiple values. Now, I need to reference another table to get the description of these multiple values as shown.

**Table A**

```
Item_No| R_code
---------------

 X       R01,R03,R04
 Y       R02,R03
 Z       R04
```

**Table B**

```
R_code| Description
------------------

R01      Missing info
R02      Invalid info
R03      Invalid Account
R04      Missing Address
```

How do I get the following result if I join Table A and Table B

**Final Result**

```
Item_no| R_code     | Description
---------------------------

 X      R01,R03,R04  Missing info,Invalid Account,Missing Address
 Y      R02,R03      Invalid info,Invalid Account
 Z      R04          Missing Address
```

Comment: This will be extremely messy - this should *really* be normalized...

Comment: @Siyual: That's how the data is stored in Table A and I need to somehow map the values to Table B. This is mainly for reporting purpose so I need to use the existing data

Comment: I would use a User Defined Function to handle this.

Comment: You have to first do an anti (reverse)-list agg to get the values on seperate rows, then a simple join, then a list_agg to put them back: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/how_to_split_a_string_into_a_set_of_rows_anti_listagg12?lang=en

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the steps how to get the desired result set?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH unpivot (lvl, item_no, r_code, tail) AS (
  SELECT 1, item_no,
         CASE WHEN LOCATE(',',r_code) > 0 
              THEN TRIM(LEFT(r_code, LOCATE(',',r_code)-1))
              ELSE TRIM(r_code) 
        END,
         CASE WHEN LOCATE(',',r_code) > 0 
              THEN SUBSTR(r_code, LOCATE(',',r_code)+1)
              ELSE '' 
         END
  FROM tableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT lvl + 1, item_no,
         CASE WHEN LOCATE(',', tail) > 0 
              THEN TRIM(LEFT(tail, LOCATE(',', tail)-1))
              ELSE TRIM(tail) 
         END,
         CASE WHEN LOCATE(',', tail) > 0 
              THEN SUBSTR(tail, LOCATE(',', tail)+1)
              ELSE '' 
         END
    FROM unpivot 
   WHERE lvl < 100 AND tail != ''),

get_desc AS
(
  SELECT item_no, up.r_code, tb.description
    FROM unpivot up
   INNER JOIN tableB tb
      ON up.item_no = tb.item_no
)

SELECT item_no,
       LISTAGG(r_code, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY r_code ASC) AS r_code,
       LISTAGG(description, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY description ASC) AS description
  FROM get_desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the query! Can you please elaborate the logic used?

Comment: I would like to mention that I will need to use this data for reporting in another query. So how do I pass the data into my reporting query? I need to send the data with multi values like show above (Final Result)